# How to read data from a logfile into variables and plot them against each other in gnuplot?

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I have a log file which is being updated continuously by a process being run on Linux. I am trying to plot Var1(Y axis) vs Var2(X axis). My current script plots them individually that is, it will will plot Var1 vs indexed values and, Var2 vs indexed values.

Since the log file is being updated continuously, I am re-reading the data.

How can I set the X axis values from Var2 ?

```
set title "Var1 vs Var2"
set xlabel "Var2"
set ylabel "Var1"

Var1="< cat ./output.txt | grep -w 'Mean and max values' |  cut -d' ' -f 9"
Var2="< cat ./output.txt | grep -w 'Time =' | cut -d'=' -f 2"

plot Var1,Var2 using lines

pause 2
reread
```

I have tried setting xtics values using `set xtics (Var2)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: How does the structure of your data file look like? Please provide some example data to get an idea about the structure. Is `Var1` a single value you get from your file or are there several values? Same for `Var2`? Do you want collect (add) new values every two seconds?

Comment: Yes ,`Var1` and `Var2` are floating point numbers and are single values. The  `cat` + `grep` +`cut` operation works well for data extraction from the log file. Yes, I want to collect data every 2 seconds since the log file is being updated continuously.    

This is a portion of the example data file: https://pastebin.com/w04V4uGK

The values of interest have strings in this format `Courant Number mean: 0.0297756 max: 0.524753
 ` and `Time = Time = 0.00041`.  This is an example file. In my original question, the max values are in a different format, but the intention remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a solution using `cat`, `grep`, `awk`, etc... might be easier, but I prefer *gnuplot-only* solutions which are also *platform-independent*.

The following solution is not obvious and probably needs some explanations:

- first set datafile separator to newline `"\n"`. This means the variable `s=strcol(1)` contains the complete line
- initialize `m` and `t` to `NaN`
- if `s` begins with your first key `Courant Number mean:` `m` will get the 6th token (i.e. the maxium value)
- if `s` begins with your first key `Time =`, `t` will get the 3th token  (i.e. the time value).
- only if `m` and `t` are not `NaN` plot `m` as y value and set `t=NaN`.

So, the plot command will go through the file and plot the found `t` versus the previously found `m`.

Furthermore:

- use `while` for a loop which you can stop by pressing `x`. Check `help bind`.
- since I don't have changing data, the script shows a random color for each pass of the loop.
- if you want to plot it with connected `lines` or `linespoints` you have do some extra steps via a table to remove the interruptions.

**Data:** `SO75929902.dat` (just a small excerpt from your file)

```
Courant Number mean: 8.74894e-05 max: 0.0315889
Time = 1e-05

PIMPLE: iteration 1
diagonal:  Solving for rho, Initial residual = 0, Final residual = 0, No Iterations 0
smoothSolver:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 1, Final residual = 8.57331e-06, No Iterations 1
...
...
...
fieldAverage fieldAverage1 write:
    Calculating averages

Courant Number mean: 0.0294733 max: 0.506002
Time = 0.0004

PIMPLE: iteration 1
diagonal:  Solving for rho, Initial residual = 0, Final residual = 0, No Iterations 0
...
```

**Script:**

```
### extract and plot values from a regularly updated file in a loop
reset session

FILE = "SO75929902.dat"

key1 = "Courant Number mean:"
key2 = "Time ="

set datafile separator "\n"
set key noautotitle
set grid x,y

continue = 1
bind x   "continue = 0"

while (continue) {
    plot m=t=NaN FILE u (s=strcol(1), s[1:strlen(key1)] eq key1 ? m=real(word(s,6)) : NaN, \
         s[1:strlen(key2)] eq key2 ? t=real(word(s,3)) : NaN, t) : \
         (m==m && t==t ? (t=NaN, m) : NaN) w lp pt 7 lc rand(0)*0xffffff
    pause 2
}
### end of script
```

**Result:** (using wxt terminal)

[image]

**Addition:**

I cannot help with `cat`, `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, etc., however, let's assume you have your data separated by spaces in two strings (`varX` and `varY`).
Then you can use the special filename `'+'` (check `help special-filenames`),  the sampling (check `help samples`) and the pseudocolumn 0, i.e. row number zero-based (check `help pseudocolumns`).
You need to set the start of the xrange[0:] manually, because default range would be `[-10:10]`.

**Script:**

```
### plot data from two strings
reset session

varX = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
varY = "9 5 6 3 7 4 8 2 1"

set samples words(varX)
x(col) = real(word(varX,int(column(col)+1)))
y(col) = real(word(varY,int(column(col)+1)))

set xrange[0:]

plot '+' u (x(0)):(y(0)) w lp pt 7 lc "red"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! This is helpful and I will accept this answer. I do not know a lot of gnuplot but  I see usage of ternary operator. I will sit down and refer to the gnuplot manual.  Alternatively, if I have to go with my idea, how can I set xticks to the variable ?

Comment: @ishan_ae I don't understand, what do you mean with "set xtics to the variable"? Do you mean having a variable e.g. `var1 = "1 2 4 8 16 32 64"` and you want the equidistant xtics to show these numbers?

Comment: Sorry. I meant to ask, how the  the values of xaxis can be set to the `Var2` values being read like this `Var2="< cat ./output.txt | grep -w 'Time =' | cut -d'=' -f 2"` .These are the time values being read from the file.